# Additional label on axis - 2D plot

Tags: plotting

I am finding a local maximum of a curve and I want to make the plot easier to read. I added a point to where the maximum is but I would also like to:

1) add a tick with text below it where the x value of the maximum is (saying "Xmax" or " X* ")

2) a dotted line from the point down to the x-axis.

Here is a simpler version of the plot I'm making:

```
maxi = FindMaximum[Cos[x], {x, 4, 8}];
coordin = {x /. maxi[[2]], First[maxi]};
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[coordin]}]
```

I have pictures to better explain this but I'm not allowed to post images.

Comment: "I have pictures to better explain this but I'm not allowed to post images." - maybe post a link to your images, and I (or somebody else) will put them in for you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
maxi = FindMaximum[Cos[x], {x, 4, 8}];
coordin = {x /. maxi[[2]], First[maxi]};
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[coordin], Dashed, 
   Line[{coordin, {coordin[[1]], 0}}], Text["X", coordin + {0.5, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: :) close! how do you put the "X" below the x axis?

Comment: How about change `Text["X", coordin + {0.5, 0}]` to `Text["X", {coordin[[1]], -0.1}]`?

Comment: Got it! Thank you! :-)